# Standalone webserver to serve HTTP GET requests

Tags: soap, fastcgi, http-get, gsoap

I'm developing a webserver(FCGI) based on using gsoap v2.8.
This webserver shall respond to the incoming HTTP GET requests but it's not working.

I got to know that gsoap provides HTTP callbacks to achieve this, In my case I'm using soap->fget callback.
I went through the gsoap documentation and I'm following the same.

[main function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpNZX.png)
[fget code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGW3z.png)

I understand that whenever there is a incoming HTTP GET requests, the soap_serve (generated by gsoap) function shall call fget callback function but I see that my function http_get is not getting hit and soap_serve is returning -1 with error message "Response-Header: \nHTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\nServer:"

I'm not sure if anything to be corrected/added in my code to handle HTTP GET requests by my webserver.

Any quick response will really help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The `fget()` callback is not invoked when FCGI or CGI is used, because the HTTP headers are stripped from the inbound message. Therefore, `soap_serve()` assumes this is a POST request by default. To respond to GET requests, do not call `soap_serve()` right away. Check the environment variable `REQUEST_METHOD` is `GET` and then produce the corresponding output. Check if the environment variable `PATH_INFO` or `PATH_TRANSLATED`  and `QUERY_STRING` match the URL your service should respond to. Never return files located on the server that are identified by `PATH_INFO` or by `QUERY_STRING`, which is a security risk. Only return files or output that should be publicly visible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm trying out based on your suggestion, so you mean without calling soap_serve, just call fget when request method is 'GET' ?

Comment: Well, calling the fget callback calls your function that is assigned to it, so you could just call your function directly.